# Selection and highlighting text on a label

Tags: iphone, objective-c, text, highlighting, gestures

I want to select and then highlight the same text on the label with a particular color.Is this be achievable with the help of gestures.
And i have to store the position of the highlighted part,even if the application terminas,so when the user comes back ,they can see that part highlighted

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes,** you could use the gesture with your `UILabel` for highlighting text by either changing the background color or text color of your `UILabel`.

You could also store the **current state** of your `UILabel` using `NSUserDefaults` , and read it back we user launch your application.

Declare an `isLabelHighlighted` as **BOOL** for `UILabel` state.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* myLabelGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(LabelClicked:)];
[myLabelView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[myLabelView addGestureRecognizer:myLabelGesture];


-(void)LabelClicked:(UIGestureRecognizer*) gestureRecognizer
{
    if(isLabelHighlighted)
    { 
         myLabelView.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    else 
    {
         myLabelView.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
}
```

To store **state** of your `UILabel`.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:isLabelHighlighted forKey:@"yourKey"];
```

To access it, you should use below.

```
isLabelHighlighted = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"yourKey"];
```

Comment: did you get answere for this? please share

Answer (score 1):

`NSUserDefaults` is not suitable, because the application can be terminated unexpectedly
`UITapGestureRecognizer` not supported any states, except `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressGestureRecognizerAction:)];
    longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.01;
    [label setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [label addGestureRecognizer:longPressGestureRecognizer];
}


- (void)longPressGestureRecognizerAction:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        label.alpha = 0.3;
    }
    else
    {
        label.alpha = 1.0;

        CGPoint point = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:label];
        BOOL containsPoint = CGRectContainsPoint(label.bounds, point);

        if (containsPoint)
        {
            // Action (Touch Up Inside)
        }
    }
}
```